# Not access from manager to node application Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Before ask my question I have to say that I am very new to Kubernetes :)

I have a created a cluster in a Bare metal cloud with two Centos machines (the manager and one worker) and I used Calico pod network. Both nodes are ready and I have deployed the helloworld application of kubernetes (I have followed this tutorial step by step): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

I can't access from my manager machine to this application, because is deployed on the worker. How could I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the master using the NodePort? It should forward the traffic to the worker.

Comment: Yes, this is my helloworld service:

NAME: my-service

CLUSTER-IP: 10.103.72.31

EXTERNAL-IP:

PORT(S): 8080:32176/TCP

AGE: 7s

When I try "curl 10.6.0.60:32176" I don't get nothing, so this is the manager url.

But when I try "curl 10.6.0.61:32176" I get "Hello Kubernetes![root@master ~]#" because this is the worker url.

Comment: Could you check that kube-proxy is running?

Comment: Yes it is, and the two nodes are connected in the cluster, I can see both when I run "kubectl get nodes"

Comment: I proved with Flannel and Calico and as I said, all the pods are ready including kube-dns.